# In gnome desktop, the mouse is on the black desktop and can't do anything on Debian 11

Tags: debian, gnome, gui, desktop

When I enter the *gnome* GUI desktop on Debian 11, the mouse is shown on the black desktop and I can't do any other things. That is my computer screen is black but the cursor is on the screen and I can move it by my mouse. It seems that the *gnome* GUI desktop is broken. So, I uninstalled the *gnome* desktop and reinstalled it. But the situation is as before. How can I repaired it. I uploaded the `Xorg*` files [here](https://doi.org/10.6084/m9.figshare.21792464.v1) from `/var/log`. I also shared them by [Onedrive](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkYaWBjatjEIgatfwDwbAbISgVLq7Q?e=e2ep7h)

Comment: Which OS? And what exactly do you mean by "the mouse is shown on the black desktop"? Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thanks for your reply and I modified the questions.

Comment: Try to use the Xorg Gnome session instead.

Comment: The symptom sounds like X11 is starting up but your desktop environment doesn't. Please [edit] to show the recent contents of pertinent log files.

Comment: @tripleee May you tell me how can I find this log file? Thanks.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov How can I install **Xorg Gnome** on Debian 11?

Comment: It must be installed by default. You should see a prompt showing you which session you're about to be logged in. You need to change it from Gnome (probably Wayland) to Gnome (Xorg/X11). I've no idea how it's worded. Please ask your questions here: https://wiki.debian.org/IRC #debian Debian is not the best distro in terms of being user-friendly, I'd recommend using Ubuntu LTS instead. If you need the freshest software Fedora is a good choice.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I see there are four choices for selection: System X11 deault, GNOME, GNOME Classic, Xfce Session. I have tested that GNOME and GNOME Classic had the same issue.

Comment: I'm notentionally vague because your question lacks enough detail to tell you exactly. Also it's been a while since I ran Gnome on Debian; but try `$HOME/.Xsession-errors` and anything in `/var/log` which mentions X11 or Wayland. There may be a separate `X.log` or `Xorg.log`, or just look in `/var/log/messages`

Comment: @tripleee I checked the `$HOME/.Xsession-errors ` but it was empty so it was 0 bytes. In  the `/var/log`, there is no `X.log` but there are `Xorg.0.log`,  `Xorg.0.log.old`,  `Xorg.1.log`,  `Xorg.1.log.old`,  `Xorg.2.log` and `Xorg.2.log.old`. There are also a file named `message`. As they are too difficult for me to read. I attatched them in the question updated. As I can't upload `messages`, so I only uploaded others.

Comment: A link where we have to download the individual logs isn't very friendly. If there is an error (`EE` or similar) in the newest log, please excerpt that (perhaps with some context) into the question itself.

Comment: @tripleee  The files has too many characters that beyond the limits. The files can be downloaded from the link, which can't be deleted.

Comment: Still, you are making it harder for us to help you; I have no good way to examine those files on my phone, and many visitors will be similarly unwilling or unable to view them.

Comment: @tripleee  Thanks for your help. I alse added shared link of onedrive from which no file is zipped. Maybe your phone can view them.